# Does "I have been meeting many people for the past few days" imply I will continue to meet people?

Tags: meaning-in-context, present-perfect-progressive

I've read that the sentence "I have been meeting many people for the past few days" implies I will continue to meet people.

Why is that the case? To me, the sentence means that I have been meeting many people for the past few days until today, but it says nothing about the future.

Does anyone agree?

Comment: It does not imply any future action at all. You'd have to look at context or tone or body language to figure out if the speaker meant that he or she would like to stop meeting people.

Answer (score 1):

It does not imply any future action at all. You'd have to look at context or tone or body language to figure out if the speaker meant that he or she would like to stop meeting people.   – FeliniusRex